# pausing android current state

Tags: android-intent, implicit

i am working on some content management app. i want to share some content through mail or sms. Here is my code to share content through sms.When i use this code i get some list of suggestion for sharing.when i click anyone of those item, that particular app get launched...
What i want now is when i press back button ,that old dialog get closed.i want that dialog to be displayed until i press back button.PLease help me as soon as possible...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
        putExtra(intent, "sms_body", body);
        // Exit the app once the SMS is sent
        intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
        launchIntent(intent);
```

Comment: Do you wanna keep open the Action chooser dialog ??

Comment: Yes.. Once i get back from the message or other app my current intent should remain with that dialog box..

Comment: your app is open ..right ? Or are you finishing it ??

Comment: Yes. i didn't use finish() function....

Comment: whats the problem you are facing while doing this?

Comment: Actually my app is about scanning qr codes.I am using zxing library for scanning.Once i scanned,i will be able to share that content thru email or sms.Fo that ia am using ACTION_SENDTO intent. When i use this  i get Action chooser dialog.after selecting the item for that dialog some new app get launched for sharing.so when i press back on that new app my old activity with that action chooser dialog   should remain displayed...

Comment: Does you app chooser have two buttons like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wxf9b.png)???

Comment: what is `launchIntent` ??

Comment: Yes i have so many suggestions

Comment: I am not asking about the suggestion. I am asking do you have button as **Just Once** and  **Always** ?? and please tell what is `launchIntent`..You are supposed to use `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`

Comment: launchIntent is a functn name where i am using startActivity.. i don't get Just Once and Always.. Instead i am getting this..https://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/legacy/Android-SDK_Share-Activity/android_share_list.png

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem i guess you dont save state of old activity

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Comment: If you dont save state of old activity , it is destroyed  and when you press back its just recreated

Comment: I have used this onStop function on main activity.Still i am unable get that dialog back.

Comment: Please someone help with this issue.I have been working on this for past 2 days...

Comment: Then use other trick , just store temporary that message in sharedpreference when you switch activities , and just call back the stored message